# INFO: Transport Used for JDBC connection: null + Apache Hive

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, hadoop, jdbc

I am trying to connect Apache Hive and eclipse through JDBC but getting below error. Following are version information:
    Apache Hadoop : 2.7.1, Hive : 1.2.1 and Eclipse Kepler.

```
****Error :****
Dec 29, 2015 6:04:00 PM org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils parseURL
INFO: Supplied authorities: localhost:10000
Dec 29, 2015 6:04:00 PM org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils parseURL
INFO: Resolved authority: localhost:10000
Dec 29, 2015 6:04:00 PM org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection openTransport
INFO: Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
Dec 29, 2015 6:04:00 PM org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection openTransport
INFO: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
Dec 29, 2015 6:04:00 PM org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection openTransport
INFO: Transport Used for JDBC connection: null
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:231)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:176)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at test.JDBCtest.main(JDBCtest.java:25)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:266)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:204)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
    ... 8 more
```

---

Code :

---

```
package test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
public class JDBCtest {
  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
   public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,      {
    try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();

      System.exit(1);
    }
    Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection
    ("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default","","");

    System.out.println("Connected");

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
    stmt.executeQuery("drop table " + tableName);
    ResultSet res = 
    stmt.executeQuery("create table "+tableName+"(key int,value);

    String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }

    sql = "describe " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
    }


    String filepath = "/tmp/a.txt";
    sql="load data local inpath'"+filepath + "' into table " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    sql = "select * from " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {


    System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getInt(1))+"\t"
    +res.getString(2));
    }

    sql = "select count(1) from " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
  }}
```

Kindly help for above error as we are facing since long time.
Thanks in advance
Mehul

Answer (score 1):

The main exception is:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

You are opening the connection without username/password in this line:

```
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default","","");
```

Please verify the username and password of your database.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I have added following user name and password from "hive-default.xml.template" file but no luck. Still getting same error logs. Please let me know in case anything still missing.                                                                                              User Name: APP
password: mine                                                                             Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "APP", "mine");